# Top bar and orbit with foundation 4

Tags: javascript

I get an issue when I use Orbit and the Top Bar of foundation 4... If I add some parameters in the foundation script, the drop down menu doens't work, if I delete these parameters, the drop down menu works, however, I wanna set parameters for the Orbit diaporama... What am I supposed to do?

The HTML code for the top bar menu :

```
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Présentation</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Domaines d'expertise</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">StenElec</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">StenLolo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">StenTherm</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Prestations</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Nos solutions</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

My script for the diaporama :

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation('orbit', {
        pause_on_hover: false
    });
</script>
```